# Can the unsigned keyword be used in non-obvious ways?

Tags: c++, c, keyword

Every time I've used the `unsigned` keyword it has been before `int`, or another built-in type. **I was wondering if there were any other ways `unsigned` could be used.**

- Can user defined types (classes/structs) use the `unsigned` keyword?
- Can templates make special use with `unsigned`?

If not, why does it have its own keyword? Why is `unsigned int` not `uint`?

Comment: Unless you mean using `unsigned` by itself (equivalent to `unsigned int`), I cannot think of any other *strange* use case.

Comment: The title of this question and the last... question in the text are quite different. Which one is it?

Comment: I've always wished I could use `unsigned` with a `bigint` class.

Comment: @Jon I've bolded the question I'm asking. The other parts I am just being curious and hoping for an explanation.

Comment: `unsigned short`, `unsigned char`? Unless you want to create special unsigned types for all the integral builtins.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You can use unsigned by itself.

Comment: Since the Q is closed: "No" on the first part. ISO/IEC 14882, 7.1.5.2 lists the valid combinations of "simple type specifiers". User-defined classes do not appear here.
4.7 (1) says "_If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer [...]_". Even if it was allowed, a user-defined type would thus need to have _a single congruent unsigned integer value_, which _may_ incidentially be the case, but is not not generally true for user-defined types.

Comment: Why was this closed? The question can be answered with a yes/no answer with a brief explanation.

Comment: ... about the second part: Yes, since signed and unsigned give different types, this can be used e.g. to differentiate between different template specialisations.

Comment: @Pubby8: Welcome to SO :) Hopefully it can re-opened soon.

Comment: @0A0D: You probably misunderstood me, the intention was to state that the least obvious way you can use `unsigned` is without any suffix, but that unless he considers that *strange* there is no other way of using `unsigned` that I can think of.

Comment: To emphasize the point, the `unsigned` keyword can only be used with integral types; `unsigned float` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it can't be used with classes or structs since they're not integral types.  All a template can do with it is make an int unsigned.  I think it was chosen as a separate keyword since it can be applied to any integer type (char, int, long, long long), thereby achieving with one keyword what would have required four more.  Its meaning is also immediately evident, whereas uint, uchar, etc. aren't necessarily.  And keep in mind it can also be used by itself without a qualifier, in which case unsigned int is assumed.

Comment: numeric is wrong, actually you should have said integral types.

Comment: More accurately, built-in integral types.  BigInt is an integral type.

Comment: @0A0D: Technically, yes, but I used the word 'numeric' specifically to highlight the fact that only numeric types can have the quality of a sign.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Understood but we shouldn't mince words here. The word integral is very important.

Comment: BTW, `long` is actually `long int`, and `long long` is `long long int` the others are short hands just as you can say `unsigned` in place of `unsigned int`... I hate this questions that lead nowhere and end up with tons of comments over imprecissions that won't make a difference...

Answer (score 5):

The main question has been answered several times: the `unsigned` keyword can only be used as a type-specifier for an integral type.

As for why `unsigned` is a separate keyword, rather than having, say, a `uint` keyword, the reasons for that are historical.

The earliest versions of C (pre-K&R) had only four fundamental types:

- `char` (8 bits, signed, 2's-complement)
- `int` (16 bits, signed, 2's-complement)
- `float` (32 bits)
- `double` (64 bits, same range as `float` but greater precision)

Note what's missing: no `signed` or `unsigned` keywords, no `short`, `long`, or `long double`; all those were added later.  (Programmers who needed unsigned arithmetic commonly used pointers, which were freely interchangeable with `int`.)

Each fundamental type had a name that was a single keyword, which made the grammar straightforward.

When other types were added later, it made sense to add specifiers like `unsigned`, `short`, and `long` to the existing type names rather than introducing new keywords (which might have broken existing code).  When the ANSI C committee standardized the language in 1989, they had to make a coherent structure out of the existing not-quite-formal definitions while remaining consistent with existing implementations.  The result is what we have now, where `int long unsigned long` is a valid type name (more commonly written as `unsigned long long`).

If the language were being designed from scratch now, I suspect that a different approach would have been taken.  Perhaps there would be a single keyword for each fundamental type (that's the approach taken by C#, for example), or perhaps the fundamental type names would use some more coherent scheme rather than a jumble of keywords (say, `int:2` for a 2-byte integer, `unsigned:4` for a 4-byte unsigned integer).  But both C and C++ are stuck with the current approach.

Reference: http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/cman.pdf

Answer (score 3):

`unsigned` is a keyword. `unsigned` can only be used on **integral** types. `unsigned` or `signed` is considered a type-specifier, a simple type-specifier. So they specify that the type will either by signed or unsigned.

You can `typedef` the words `unsigned int` to `uint` but then that would make it look like a type when `int` is the type and `unsigned` is the type-specifier per se.

You can use `unsigned` by itself, contrary to popular belief, as evidenced in the C++ ISO Standard Section 7.1.5.2 Table 7:

[image]

You can use multiple type-specifiers (when only allowed) and can be freely mixed with decl-specifiers in any order.

You can also do this:

```
int unsigned i;
```

and this is valid C++.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>No unsigned isn't really a keyword on its own; it's only a modifier for int, short, char.</strike>

The `unsigned` keyword can be used as a modifier for `int`, `short`, `char`, or `long`.  It can also be used on its own as a type name; `unsigned` means `unsigned int`.

It was done that way to avoid having three extra keywords uint ushort uchar and because signed/unsigned might not have been different on all the early computers C and Unix were aimed at.

Comment: well, actually it is a `type-specifier` not `modifier`. See 7.1.5 in the C++ ISO Standard.

Comment: @Sanjay: I don't care what that says, go read the ISO standard in 7.1.5. http://www-d0.fnal.gov/~dladams/cxx_standard.pdf

Comment: @0A0D - 'modifier' in the English sense seemed a simpler explanation

Comment: It certainly is a keyword.  It happens to be used as a type-specifier.

Comment: `unsigned` is listed in the table of keywords in the standard so it is actually a keyword, and it even denotes a type when used by itself (it is equivalent to `unsigned int`). And @Sanjay, 0A0D is right, it is a type-specifier and more precisely a *simple-type-specifier* according to the grammar in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

The keywords signed, unsigned, short, and long are type modifiers/specifier and When one of these type modifiers/specifier is used by itself, a data type of int is assumed.

So signed and unsigned may also be `used as standalone type specifiers`, meaning the same as signed int and unsigned int respectively. The following two declarations are equivalent:

```
unsigned abc;

unsigned int abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also unsigned char. Some compilers, such as GNU's g++, let you just put unsigned and assume you mean unsigned int. For example the following code is equivalent

```
unsigned int x;

unsigned x;
```

Answer (score 0):

SerenityOS has a blog post about how they redefine `unsigned` to `signed` briefly to implement `size_t` in their headers: https://awesomekling.github.io/How-SerenityOS-declares-ssize_t/

```c
#define unsigned signed
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ ssize_t;
#undef unsigned
```

This may look hackish but if you are only supporting GCC/Clang), which are the only compilers to implement `__SIZE_TYPE__`, and need to compile freestanding without any system libraries (as is the case for kernels), then this approach to defining `ssize_t` is solid, reliable, and far more maintainable than a nasty maze of `#ifdef`s.

For reference and curiosity, let's investigate how/when `ssize_t` is normally defined on my x86_64 Linux Mint machine.

`ssize_t` can be defined on-demand in a number of different places such as `<stdio.h>` when `__USE_XOPEN2K8` is defined (old old legacy stuff). BUT, the primary place `ssize_t` is defined is on lines 107-110 of `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h`, which is typically brought in by including `<unistd.h>`. Here are lines 107-110:

```c
#ifndef __ssize_t_defined
typedef __ssize_t ssize_t;
# define __ssize_t_defined
#endif
```

The `__ssize_t` comes from line 193 of `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h`:

```c
__STD_TYPE __SSIZE_T_TYPE __ssize_t; /* Type of a byte count, or error.  */
```

The `__SSIZE_T_TYPE` comes from line 73 of `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/typesizes.h`:

```c
#define __SSIZE_T_TYPE      __SWORD_TYPE
```

The `__SWORD_TYPE` comes from lines 115-114 of `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h`:

```c
#if __WORDSIZE == 32
# define __SQUAD_TYPE       __int64_t
# define __UQUAD_TYPE       __uint64_t
# define __SWORD_TYPE       int
# define __UWORD_TYPE       unsigned int
# define __SLONG32_TYPE     long int
# define __ULONG32_TYPE     unsigned long int
# define __S64_TYPE     __int64_t
# define __U64_TYPE     __uint64_t
/* We want __extension__ before typedef's that use nonstandard base types
   such as `long long' in C89 mode.  */
# define __STD_TYPE     __extension__ typedef
#elif __WORDSIZE == 64
# define __SQUAD_TYPE       long int
# define __UQUAD_TYPE       unsigned long int
# define __SWORD_TYPE       long int
# define __UWORD_TYPE       unsigned long int
# define __SLONG32_TYPE     int
# define __ULONG32_TYPE     unsigned int
# define __S64_TYPE     long int
# define __U64_TYPE     unsigned long int
/* No need to mark the typedef with __extension__.   */
# define __STD_TYPE     typedef
#else
# error
#endif
```

The `__WORDSIZE` comes from lines 3-9 of `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h`:

```c
#if defined __x86_64__ && !defined __ILP32__
# define __WORDSIZE 64
#else
# define __WORDSIZE 32
#define __WORDSIZE32_SIZE_ULONG     0
#define __WORDSIZE32_PTRDIFF_LONG   0
#endif
```

The `__x86_64__` and `__ILP32__` are both predefined macros provided by the compiler and baked into the compiler's binary from the makefile that built it from its source code.

All files under `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` are specific to the native x86_64 architecture of my computer, and x86_64 is exclusively the SysV 64-bit extension of the x86 ABI.

The check for `defined __x86_64__ && !defined __ILP32__` is only false if using the x86_64 compiler with `-m32` or `-mx32` to force it to generate 32-bit or x32-abi code, respectively. However, the more common approach to compile 32-bit binaries is to install the respective GCC multiarch compiler.

For comparison, musl libc takes a much shorter rout and just defines all the types to their respective fixed-width integers on an architecture-specific-header basis. For x86_64: https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/arch/x86_64/bits/stdint.h?id=3f08154ac494f4739afbc7451f317b2ef1bffbd3

Comment: Note that preprocessor hacks are unnecessary with either standard C23 or GNU C11, since a C++-style `make_unsigned` can easily be implemented with `_Generic` + `typeof` ... though I haven't tested with the new `_BitInt(N)` types. With older GNU C it's also possible with `__builtin_classify_type` or `__builtin_types_compatible_p`, but much uglier.